# PHP/mysql how do i echo data from my db to textboxes, with a logined user

Tags: php, mysql

ok the story is 
i'm making a helpdesk

and of course im logged in, and i want my logged in info such as my First name to be automatically appear in the textbox.. and make the textbox  uh, "unchangeable"

i'm able to get my "current logged in account"  stuff...

How do i do that?
http://postimg.org/image/ts98d7stp/full/

this is my helpdesk.php btw

```
        <?php 
    $action=$_REQUEST['action']; 
    if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */ 
        { 
        ?> 
        <form  action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit"> 
        Your name:<br> 
        <input name="name" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> 
        Your email:<br> 
        <input name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> 
        Your message:<br> 
        <textarea name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br> 
        <input type="submit" value="Send email"/> 
        </form> 
        <?php 
        }  
    else                /* send the submitted data */ 
        { 
        $name=$_REQUEST['name']; 
        $email=$_REQUEST['email']; 
        $message=$_REQUEST['message']; 
        if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($message=="")) 
            { 
            echo "All fields are required, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a> again."; 
            } 
        else{         
            $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email"; 
            $subject="Message sent using your contact form"; 
            mail("crosswayprinting42@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $from); 
            echo "Email sent!"; 
            } 
        }   
    ?>
```

/* this part where i test echo my current logged in data, now i need to know how do i put it in a textbox and disable text editing/typing on it */

```
 <table cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="example" >
        <thead>
        <tr>


        <th>First Name</th>     <!-- 4 -->
        <th>Last Name</th>  <!-- 4 -->
        <th>Middle Name</th>    <!-- 4 -->
        <th>Email</th>  <!-- 4 -->
        <th>Address</th>    <!-- 4 -->

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr>



            <td><?php echo $row['userfirstName']; ?></td>   <!-- 4 -->
            <td><?php echo $row['userlastName']; ?></td>    <!-- 4 -->
            <td><?php echo $row['usermiddleName']; ?></td>  <!-- 4 -->
            <td><?php echo $row['userEmail']; ?></td>       <!-- 5 -->
            <td><?php echo $row['userAddress']; ?></td>     <!-- 5 -->
```

Comment: Please show your code. That'd be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **should create $_SESSION variables** from the loged user and put them into the textboxes like this:

```
<input name="name" type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>"size="30"/>
```

hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Change `$looged_in` with your variable.

`<input type="text" value="<?php echo $logged_in; ?>">`